# Passar valor de um getJSON para uma variável

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    $('#aprovados').click( function(){
  var job = $.getJSON($(this).attr("data-ajax-info-job"),
    function(jobinfo){
       return jobinfo }
  );
  console.log(job)
  });
```

A ideia era retorna os meus dados json que vem do meu backend mas eu recebo como se fosse um log da requisição. Como eu poderia mudar esse código para receber apenas o json que preciso?

Comment: O getJSON é assíncrono, logo o console.log(job) não irá esperar o retorno do Ajax.

Comment: Ou seja, vc vai precisar trabalhar com os dados dentro da função do getJSON

Comment: Entendi mas teria alguma forma de eu conseguir pegar esse valor?

Comment: com $.ajax é possível usando async, mas não é recomendado :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) é assíncrona, o retorno desta chamada não será imediatamente resolvido...você deves "observar" o callback caso queira executar algo somente após ter um retorno.

```
var job; // reserve a variável
// faça o pedido (requisição)
$.getJSON($(this).attr("data-ajax-info-job"),function(jobinfo) {
    // atribuir
    job = jobinfo;
})
```

Ou você pode atrelar o retorno a uma função:

```
function executarAlgumaTarefa(param) {
    console.log(param)
}
// faça o pedido (requisição)
$.getJSON($(this).attr("data-ajax-info-job"),executarAlgumaTarefa)
```

Comment: Obrigado Man! Consegui.